# Making a text box box visible on a select change

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a select and textbox. If you select 'Not listed' a responseText returns 'Unknown' and then I would like to make the textbox visible. The textbox is in a div.

```
<div id='qualification'>
<input type='text'>
</div>
```

When an item is chosen from a select then this part of script makes the textbox hidden (for testing purposes as I really want this to show the textbox and not hide it, but shows things are working):

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'Unknown') {
    $('#qualification').hide();
}
```

However if I set the div up to be hidden at the start:

```
<div id='qualification' style='visibility: hidden'>
```

and then change

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'Unknown') {
    $('#qualification').show();
}
```

it does not work. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: change `<div id='qualification' style='visibility: hidden'>` to `<div id='qualification' style='display:none;'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility needs changing instead

```
$('#qualification').css('visibility','visible');
```

`display: none != visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `display` property instead of `visibility` :

```
<div id='qualification' style='display: none'>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT

Actually that should be

```
display:none;
```